# Loss of context. setTimeout

Tags: javascript

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
    var self = this;

    return function() {
        setTimeout(self, ms);
    };
}

function f(a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
}

f.defer(5000)(1, 2); // 3
```

Should show the number 3 in 5 seconds, but somehow deduced NaN.

Comment: You are not passing the arguments along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're passing `setTimeout` the function but the parameters `1, 2` are not bound to it, so it's calling `f` with no arguments.

You can fix it like this:

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
    var self = this;

    return function() {
        var args = arguments,
            context = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
            self.apply(context, args);
        }, ms);
    };
}

function f(a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
}

f.defer(5000)(1, 2); // 3
```

Comment: Ok. I understand everything. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The function that `defer` returns doesn't take any arguments, so the `1` and `2` are ignored.

If you want to use them, then you need to capture them and do something with them.

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
    var self = this;

    return function(x, y) {
        setTimeout(self.bind(this, x, y), ms);
    };
}

function f(a, b) {
    alert(a + b);
}

f.defer(5000)(1, 2); // 3
```